# READFITS undefined in IDL

Tags: undefined, astronomy, idl-programming-language

I just started working with IDL for my summer undergraduate lab, so I'm still kinda new to the program.

I've been trying to load a FITS file to analyze the data into the program, but for some reason IDL won't recognize the instruction of "READFITS".

My input is:

```
image = readfits('test.fits', h, /NOSCALE)
```

I get the following error:

```
% Attempt to call undefined procedure/function: READFITS
```

I've looked for alternative way to load FITS files, or if I need to install an additional package, but apparently the instruction should be already with IDL.

Answer (score 3):

`READFITS` is not part of IDL. It is part of the [IDL Astronomy User's Library](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov). Download it and add it to IDL's `!path`.

Answer (score 2):

Or after downloading it as @mgalloy suggested, keep it in the current working directory since IDL will search the current directory for it as well.